# Is is possible to preserve the stack trace of an exception when I create a new one?

Tags: c#

I would like to define son custom exceptions for a repository, so in this way, the application layer will receive the same kind of exceptions, no matter the implementation or technology used in my repository.

Well, my repository is something like this:

```
public async Task<MyType?> GetDataAsync(long paramLgId)
{
    try
    {
        MyType? myResult = await _context.MyType
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == paramLgId);

        return myResult;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw EntityCoreExceptionsHelper.GetExcepcion(ex);
    }
}
```

This is my exceptions helper:

```
public static class EntityCoreExceptionsHelper
{
    public static Exception GetExcepcion(Exception paramExcepcion)
    {
        SqlException? myExcepcionSql = paramExcepcion as SqlException;


        if(myExcepcionSql != null)
        {
            if(myExcepcionSql.Number == -1)
            {
                return new BaseDeDatosNoAccesibleException("Server not available.", myExcepcionSql);
            }

            else if (myExcepcionSql.Number == 4060)
            {
                return new BaseDeDatosNoAccesibleException("DataBaseNotAvailable.", myExcepcionSql);
            }


            return new ExcepcionIndeterminadaException("Unexpected exception.", myExcepcionSql);
        }



        return new ExcepcionIndeterminadaException("Unexpected exception.", paramExcepcion);
    }
```

The problem with this solution is that the stack trace marks the line in the catch in the repository class, when I use throw EntityCoreExceptionsHelper.GetExcepcion(ex); instead of the linea in which I perform the query.

It is true that I can get the line in the inner exception, but to know the line of the real exception, I have to go to the inner exception, and if there is many innter exceptions, I should have to iterate over all the inner exceptions.

There is some way to have the complete stack trace in the last exception, in the upper exception, to avoid to have to check all the inner exceptions?

I Have read about ExceptionDispatchInfo, but the examples that I have seen are to capture the exception and throw it, not creating a new kind of exception, so I don't know how to capture the original exception and create new exception with the original stack trace.

So in sumary, is it possible to have the whole stack trace with the real line of the exception?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the InnerException property to preserve the original exception.

Comment: There is no need for that. `Ecxeption.ToString()` will always append the message and stacktrace of all inner exceptions. Every sane error reporting tool (e.g. Sentry) will also do that. Also it's common for exception helper functions to pop up in dotnet framework stacktraces. They're noise but not unusual. Chances are that by hiding your exception helper you will only cause confusion for other programmers.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride It is true the using a helper it could couse confusing to another programmers, but if I use the inner exception, the information is there. The reason to use a helper it is becaose of IoC. In the application layer I define an interface and it receive the implementation of a resource. How it can be injected differen implementations that could throw different exceptions, in this way, I define the exceptions that implementations should to throw, as contract, so the application layer is less coupling to different implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`ExceptionDispatchInfo.SetRemoteStackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.setremotestacktrace?view=net-7.0) available since .NET 6:

> Stores the provided stack trace into the specified Exception instance.

> This method populates the StackTrace property from an arbitrary string value. The typical use case is the transmission of Exception objects across processes with high fidelity, allowing preservation of the exception object's stack trace information. .NET does not attempt to parse the provided string value.
> The caller is responsible for canonicalizing line endings if required. ReplaceLineEndings() can be used to canonicalize line endings.
> If the caller provides untrusted input to this API, this may result in the exception's stack trace containing embedded null characters, reserved HTML or JSON characters, or other unexpected values. Applications that display an exception's details to the user should always take care to encode the exception information at the point where it's displayed.

```cs
void Throws()
{
    throw new Exception();
}

try
{
    Throws();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    var e = new InvalidOperationException();
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.SetRemoteStackTrace(e, exception.StackTrace);
    throw e;
}
```

Which generates the following stacktrace for my sample app:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
> at Program.<$>g__Throws|0_0() in D:\Projects\Playground\src\csharp\SOAnswers\NET7\NET7Console\Program.cs:line 32
> at Program.$(String[] args) in D:\Projects\Playground\src\csharp\SOAnswers\NET7\NET7Console\Program.cs:line 37
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Program.$(String[] args) in D:\Projects\Playground\src\csharp\SOAnswers\NET7\NET7Console\Program.cs:line 43

Compared to one with `throw new InvalidOperationException();`:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
> at Program.$(String[] args) in D:\Projects\Playground\src\csharp\SOAnswers\NET7\NET7Console\Program.cs:line 44

Though personally I would go with the inner exception approach.